# Joining DataTable with LinQ and return as DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a 2 separate data sources. One is from a database query and will be returned as a DataTable, and one other is from somewhere else and returned as a Dictionary.

I would like to join these 2 data sources together and combine it into 1 DataTable. So here is the code:

```
string query = @"select ID, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE from PERSON a";

OracleCommand dbCommand = (OracleCommand)this.Database.GetSqlStringCommand(query) as OracleCommand;
DataTable dtPerson = this.Database.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0];

Dictionary<string, DTMember> member = GetMember();

// Join the 2 results
var result = (from a in dtPerson.AsEnumerable()
    join b in member on a.Field<string>("ID") equals b.Key into b1
    from b in b1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        a,
        MEMBER_TYPE = b.Value == null ? string.Empty : b.Value.MemberType
    });

return result.ToDataTable();
```

The thing is that, since that I write as `a` in the `select new` clause, it will return all fields in `dtPerson` as a `DataRow` object instead of all the field names (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE). So that each row in `result` will contain 2 members, one is a `DataRow` and other one is a `string`.

Can I write in a way to return all the columns in `dtPerson` without specifying it one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a reflection  based approach for this. It's simple:

```
var query = 
    from a in dtPerson.AsEnumerable()
    join b in member on a.Field<string>("ID") equals b.Key into b1
    from b in b1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        PersonRow  = a,
        MemberType = b.Value?.MemberType ?? String.Empty
    };

DataTable resultTable = dtPerson.Clone(); // empty same columns
resultTable.Columns.Add("MemberType");    // add this column

foreach (var x in query)
{
    object[] allFields = x.PersonRow.ItemArray.Concat(new []{x.MemberType}).ToArray();
    resultTable.Rows.Add(allFields);
}

return resultTable;
```